# How to convert XML to MindMap?

Tags: xml, xslt, mindmapping, mindmap, freemind

I have checked many tools like "freemind", "freeplane", etc. Most of them allow exporting to XML file output but I didn't get how to convert an XML to a MindMap.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both, FreeMind and Freeplane, can import from several XML formats but there is no general XML-to-mindmap converter since there are many, many existing XML formats and for each format you need a distinct mapping from the different XML elements, attributes, sub-elements and what more to the different elements (node text, maybe attributes, notes, ...) in a mindmap.

FreeMind and Freeplane use an XML dialect as their own proprietary file format (.mm) so one way to convert some XML to a mindmap would be a XML-to-XML transformation via XSLT or Xquery. Both programs also understand to import indented text like this

```
root node
  first child
    grandchild
  second child
```

as a node hierarchy, e.g. when pasted into a map.

References:

- [FreeMind/Freeplane file formats](http://freeplane.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Current_Freeplane_File_Format)
- Existing Import/Export filters of [FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Import_and_export_to_other_applications) and [Freeplane](https://github.com/freeplane/freeplane/tree/master/freeplane/resources/xslt)

Comment: Freeplane can import arbitrary xml files as mind maps since version 1.5.6 (current beta)

Comment: Regarding "import indented text" in FreeMind, you need to copy/paste it, you can't actually import it without plugins. [Plain text in FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Import_and_export#Plain_text)

Answer (score 1):

[Astah Professional](http://astah.net/editions/professional) supports XML import/export.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion can be done manually:
open in a text editor

```
  remove <header></header> part
  remove  <Content> and </Content> tag
  replace <Root> and </Root> by  <map> and </map> (case sensitive)
  replace "Title" by "TEXT"

  rename extension from xml to mm
```

open with vym rather than freeplane